# How to add a constraint to an object

Tags: oracle, plsql

to execute the code : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=69131953cf61459b64092025737d79b7

I have a object that has several field.
And I want to say that a field can have only certain values.

I tried to do that the same way I would do it with a table

```
create type oa as object(
  a VARCHAR2(59) constraint cta check(a in ('a1','a2' ))
)
```

> ORA-24344: success with compilation error

I have tried to create a table and say that my object has the same fields

```
CREATE TABLE ta(
        a VARCHAR2(59) constraint cta check(a in ('a1','a2' ))
    )

Create type oa2 as  ta%rowtype
```

> ORA-24344: success with compilation error

It doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot; constraints can only be applied to tables or views.

From the [`constraint` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE):

> Constraint clauses can appear in the following statements:
>
> - `CREATE TABLE` (see [`CREATE TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6))
> - `ALTER TABLE` (see [`ALTER TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877))
> - `CREATE VIEW` (see [`CREATE VIEW`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html#GUID-61D2D2B4-DACC-4C7C-89EB-7E50D9594D30))
> - `ALTER VIEW` (see [`ALTER VIEW`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ALTER-VIEW.html#GUID-0DEDE960-B481-4B55-8027-EA9E4C863625))

---

As an alternative, you can declare the type as:

```sql
CREATE TYPE oa as object(
  a VARCHAR2(59)
);
```

Then declare an object-derived table with an added `CHECK` constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE oat OF oa (
  CONSTRAINT oat_chk CHECK (a in ('a1', 'a2'))
);
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO oat VALUES (oa('a1'));
INSERT INTO oat (a) VALUES ('a1');
```

works but:

```sql
INSERT INTO oat VALUES (oa('b1'));
INSERT INTO oat (a) VALUES ('b1');
```

Violates the check constraint.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8e60a3bd25c097c95059167540e2d43c)*